# Need to figure out a mechanism to send emails to the case contacts via action button in the case record page layout

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I was looking for a way to notify the case contact, via email, whenever someone handling the case wants to inform the case contact about the case status and case comments.

I'm a beginner and need help on deciding the solution. I assume I'll need to write an apex method for sending the email to the case contact with required content. Now I need a custom button in the case record page layout which triggers the apex method. The quick action button in case object setup page doesn't have any option to trigger an apex method. So am I supposed to create a custom button using Aura or Lightning Web Components? Does LWC work in salesforce production/sandbox instance or its it only available in scratch orgs?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using email quick action by pre-defining the **To** field of email action based on condition you want.

> Steps to Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields

1. Click the name of an action in the Buttons, Links, and Actions list
   or the Global Actions list.
2. On the action detail page, click New in the Predefined Field Values
   list.
3. Select the field you want to predefine a value for.
4. Specify the value for the field. For single-select picklists, you
   can specify both a specific value and a formula value.If you set both, the formula value takes precedence over the specific value.
5. Click Save.

Read more here:- [set Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5)

Note:- You will need to write some trigger logic on contact and create one field on Case to store the Emails of the contacts associated with Case by updating by contact trigger and store in this format:-

```
a@a.com;b@b.com;c@c.com
```

Comment: Isn't only one contact associated to a case? I'll also need to add all the case comments in the email body. Would that be possible in the email template? One hackish way I got to know from a forum is by adding a text field(hidden from UI) that stores all the case comments and is updated on each new case comment using trigger or process builder. Then using that field in the email template. But I don't think it will work out quite well for cases when a user edits an old comment (it will be added as a new comment by the trigger).

Comment: You can raise a seperate question for your this query.